# Где правильно хранить обработчики событий? Где правильно хранить логику непосредственно игрового процесса?

Tags: java, javafx

я пытаюсь реализовать приложение "Тамагочи" используя JavaFX. В силу того, что программированием занимаюсь совсем недавно, очень путаюсь в логике программы. Я не пользуюсь SceneBuilder и fxml, поэтому все элементы описаны в коде.

Класс SceneCreator содержит в себе методы для построения сцен. Они загружаются в Main. При запуске программы отрисовывается первая сцена. По нажатию кнопки "Новая игра" должно обрабатываться событие, которое вызывает построение второй сцены.

Где правильно хранить обработчики событий? Где правильно хранить логику непосредственно игрового процесса?

```
public class SceneCreator {

    public Stage frame;

    public void createFirstScene () {

        Button bNewGame = new Button("Новая игра");
        bNewGame.setPrefSize(180, 40);

        Button bContGame = new Button("Продолжить игру");
        bContGame.setPrefSize(180, 40);

        Button bExitGame = new Button("Покинуть игру");
        bExitGame.setPrefSize(180, 40);


        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        grid.setVgap(30);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        grid.add(bNewGame, 1, 0);
        grid.add(bContGame, 1, 1);
        grid.add(bExitGame, 1, 2);

        Scene firstScene = new Scene(grid, 300, 350);

        firstScene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/View/general.css").toExternalForm());

        frame.setScene(firstScene);

        bNewGame.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                createSecondScene();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createSecondScene () {

       // наполнение второй сцены

        Scene secondScene = new Scene(new Group());
        frame.setScene(secondScene);
    }

}
```

Класс Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main (String args []) {
        launch(args);
    }

    SceneCreator sceneCreator= new SceneCreator();

    public void start (Stage stage) {

        sceneCreator.frame = stage;

        sceneCreator.frame.setTitle("Application");
        sceneCreator.frame.setResizable(false);
        sceneCreator.createFirstScene();
        sceneCreator.frame.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: "как правильно" -- это вопрос, на который нельзя дать правильный ответ. Это зависит от ситуации, от ваших планов и т. д. В общем, всем новичкам (да и не только) приходится совершать ошибки, иногда потом всё приходится перепахивать, в корне меняя архитектуру. Это вопрос тонкий, тут не столько знания каких-то правил помогают, сколько опыт и интуиция. Но знания тоже нужны. Почитайте Gamma ..."Design patterns" и еще что-нибудь по проектированию, шаблонам и т. п. Конкретно по JavaFX могу посоветовать Kishori Sharan. "Learn JavaFX 8." -- толковая и подробная, и есть целая отдельная глава по MVC.

Comment: Из всех начальных учебников по Java, как мне помнится, только Эккель не только описывает, как использовать наследование, полиморфизм, ограничения доступа и т. п. , но и объясняет, зачем это нужно в контексте более широких программистских задач. Тоже советую.

Comment: @Olyoshaaa Напоминаю, что можно голосовать за ответы, и если он отвечает на ваш вопрос, то можно отметить как решение

Answer (score 1):

По поводу вопроса разделения логики и обработки событий - ответ: использовать паттерн проектирования **MVC**.

В нем как раз таки разделяется все приложение на самостоятельные части:

- **View** (представление) - в вашем случае это SceneCreator. Представление содержит все что связано с отображением чего либо на экране
- **Model** (бизнес-логика) - как раз таки логика вашего приложения (непосредственно игрового процесса)
- **Controller** (контроллер событий) - составная часть отвечающая за обработку всех событий

Подробнее об MVC:

> http://maxsite.org/page/java-mvc *MVC (Model View Controller) в
>   JavaFX*

Comment: Спасибо большое, это очень полезно!